# Rotating image while animating

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to create custom animation. I have hearth image which goes from bottom left corner to top right one. I will be animating top and bottom values of image to get it across the screen. The only catch is that I want it to rotate a little bit in the middle of a road, and then rotate back to first state. Is such animation doable? If so, could you give me advise how can i code it?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the image with the `rotate` property of `transform` and use your animated value there. Example:

```
var interpolatedRotateAnimation = this._animatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 100],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
});
```

You can find an example [here](http://browniefed.com/react-native-animation-book/basic/ROTATE.html)